# onchange function for select when there is a single option

Tags: javascript

How can i invoke a on change function when there is a single option. I am aware of the option by adding a dummy 'select' option.

```
<select onchange='myfunction'>
<option value ='1'>1<option>
<select>
```

Comment: Why would you have a select with only one option? The whole point is to allow different options.

Comment: @AndrewL. It's probably generated dynamically, and in some cases there's only one option.

Comment: @AndrewL. Imagine a form where you select a city, and it then populates a menu of zip codes. Many cities only have one zip code.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting, fair enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onclick` to detect clicking on any option in the `<select>`.

```js
function myfunction() {
  console.log('clicked');
}
```

```html
<select onclick='myfunction()'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
</select>
```